# Core Plot extremely slow on iOS?

Tags: ios, performance, core-plot

I am having issues with a simple X/Y scatter plot with Core Plot 2.0 on iOS 7.1

The following plot code:

```
CPTGraphHostingView* graphHostView;
CPTXYGraph* graph;
CPTScatterPlot* plot;
CPTXYPlotSpace* plotSpace;
DebugLog(@"Initializing GRAPH HOST VIEW");

graphHostView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 200)];
[self addSubview: graphHostView];

// Create a CPTGraph object and add to hostView
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:graphHostView.bounds];
graphHostView.hostedGraph = graph;

// Get the (default) plotspace from the graph so we can set its x/y ranges
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;

// Note that these CPTPlotRange are defined by START and LENGTH (not START and END) !!
[plotSpace setYRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat( 0 ) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat( 20000 )]];
[plotSpace setXRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat( 0 ) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat( 6 )]];

// Create the plot (we do not define actual x/y values yet, these will be supplied by the datasource...)
plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

plot.dataSource = dataSource;

[graph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];
```

takes just about 60 seconds to complete grinding at 100% CPU usage, and allocating steadily up to 300 MB RAM. What could be up? The graph is being hosted in a "parent" UIView.

I have used Core Plot before, and while it seemed slow, this is clearly totally unacceptably slow! What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using dispatch_async when updating my graph. For example, in my code i Used:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self setupGraph];
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I can't follow this, why would that help? The app would still be stuck in the runloop?

Comment: I wish I could explain it better but give it a try (put your setup code into the main queue) and let me know your result. I've seen some other tasks that seem to run faster in the main queue such as updating UI text. I'm not able to explain it but if it also works for you it would be worth investigating further into why it works.

Comment: it doesn't and I don't see why it would. fwiw, the core performance issue (at least for me) seems to be axis label updates as described in other "CorePlot is slow questions on SO.